# How to copy virtualenv to another machine which doesn't have the same interpreter?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv on my local machine and I would like to copy this virtualenv to a production machine which is the same platform but it does not have python3 and I cannot install it.

Is it possible to copy the virtualenv and python3 interpreter to the production machine which doesn't have the same python version?

I have tried relocatable for virtualenv and pip freezes. I copied the venv and changed active paths but it didn't help, it cannot run pip or python commands because it cannot find the interpreter.

Comment: Have you had a look into Anaconda? Basically you need to install the interpreter. Anaconda handles dependencies for you (including interpreter install).

Comment: What stops you from installing python3 on the prod machine? Access rights or dependencies?

Comment: I will check Anaconda thanks. I cannot install because owner does not allow me to install, centos has some python3 issues he said.

Comment: You will need the rights to install something. Which doesn't mean you will need admin rights. More info here: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html

Comment: Anaconda solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda solved my problem with the following steps:

**Replica Server(can be local or VM):**

1. Create a download directory and download-install Anaconda. Change username to yours. Username must be same as the real or prod server!

   `mkdir /home/username/download
    cd /home/username/download
    wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
    bash /home/umut.ataman/Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`
2. Export the path that you would like anaconda-python to be and create virtual env.

   `mkdir /data/anaconda/bin
    export PATH=/data/anaconda/bin:$PATH
    conda create -n anenv python=3.7.0 anaconda`
3. [Optional] Activate venv and install requirements for the project(if you need basic installment before copy).

   `source /data/mavenrepo/anaconda/bin/activate anenv
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed six`

**Server to copy.**
- SHH copy the anaconda directory to real-prod server and activate your venv. Do not forget to check version of python.

```
`scp -r root@10.1.1.1:/data/anaconda/* /data/anaconda/
 source /data/mavenrepo/anaconda/bin/activate anenv
 python -V`
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you don't copy virtualenv to a production machine. Instead, Create a [PEX](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) file & ask admins to install python3 on production host.

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is a concept for developers. As developers are working on different projects and different projects use different version of libraries. Virtualenv provides solution to this kind of problem.

PEX (Python Executable) is equivalent to .exe file.